# Wordpress theme header.php should I add title meta?

Tags: theme-development, custom-header

I am making a theme for WordPress and I have noticed that most themes does not have  meta in them
Is there any specific reason for this?

Am I allowed to put custom metas such as keywords that are SEO related while publishing to WordPress directory?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in the [theme review requirements](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/), but there's a link to a Slack channel there where you could ask? If you do, please come back and post the answer here.

Comment: @Rup Okay thanks. I also didn't see anything like that, asking because most of the themes including twentytwentyone does not it have in base theme. Head should have a title as per HTML validator.

Comment: Oh, if you meant the actual <title> tag then the modern way is [`add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag) and let WordPress itself generate it in wp_head. (And that's [actually mandatory now](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2015/08/25/title-tag-support-now-required/).) I thought you meant <meta> tags - I don't know if there's any standard for that.

Comment: @Rup That's the part that is missing. Thank you. I will check more on having meta-title, meta-description. or maybe I will control it with an action or option.

Comment: Generally none of that stuff should be added to header.php. It should be added via a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't. This is not the theme's job. Your theme's header.php just needs to include `wp_head()`, which will allow WordPress and plugins to add any necessary tags to the `<head>`.